# Why does execve() does not return on success?

Tags: unix, execve

I have read the man pages.

All I understood from this link http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/zid-7281.htm is that 
`A successful call to execve does not have a return value because the new process image overlays the calling process image`

I am not very clear as to why this will happen ? And if the new process overlays the calling process, why does it return on failure only and not on success ?

Comment: Because `execve` essentially replaces your current program with the new program. How and where can it return if the calling program doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Because if it fails to do what it is trying to do, i.e. replace the process with the new one, then it makes sense to return, to inform the caller that it failed.

If it succeeds, then the code that called `execve()` is no longer present, it has been replaced by the successful execution of that function, so obviously it cannot do anything any more. Returning is such a thing.

Comment: I see, so how does it handle the scenario if some error happens while executing the new process ? At this point, the execve() has successfully started the new process, but now it has encountered an error sometime after that.

Comment: @AgnivaDeSarker If the new process fails, then that has nothing to do with `execve()`. It's execution is binary: if it succeeds, it *replaces* the calling process' code with the new code. That means the `execve()` call itself ceases to exist. If it fails, it returns back out so the application can deal with the error.